# Scraping data from website into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I navigate to a site using vba and get to where I need to be using a form. I need the vba to grab some data from the HTML and put it into an excel sheet. How can I scrap this data into excel?

Here is a piece from the page:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_pnlListaContas">


            <table width="800px" border="0">
                <tr>

                    <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl00_tdRadioButtonHeader" width="35px" class="td_titulo"></td>

                    <td width="130px" class="td_titulo">Nº Conta Energia
                    </td>
                    <td width="100px" class="td_titulo">Descrição Fatura
                    </td>
                    <td width="80px" class="td_titulo">Mês Ref.
                    </td>
                    <td width="100px" class="td_titulo">Vencimento
                    </td>

                    <td width="100px" class="td_titulo">Valor
                    </td>
                    <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl00_tdCodBarrasHeader" width="200px" class="td_titulo">Código de Barras
                    </td>


                </tr>


            <tr id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_linha">
            <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_tdRadioButtonItem" width="35px" class="td_branco">
                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_rbConta" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridDebitosUsuario1$rptContasAberto$ctl01$rbConta" value="0201701001618299" onclick="SetUniqueRadioButton(&#39;rptContasAberto.*rbConta&#39;,this);" />
                </td>
            <td width="130px" class="td_branco">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_lblNumeroConta">0201701001618299</span>
```

I'm trying the code below, but it's not working:

```
Set xobj = objIe.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_pnlListaContas")
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl00_tdRadioButtonHeader")
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByClassName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_lblNumeroConta")(0)

    MsgBox xobj.innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question specifically since you ask for an Excel solution, but when I need to scrape a website and get results into Excel, I use Web Scraper, an extension for Chrome. It is a bit annoying in the beginning because it is not exactly an intuitive extension and the help is very limited, but once you get the hang of it, it works pretty well. The results of a scrape can be exported to CSV format.

http://webscraper.io/

Comment: Jonh, thanks for your tip But I enjoy VBA most and also it's easeast for me to work with it.

Comment: If you have Office installed on your computer there should be an IE context menu extension installed called "Export to Microsoft Excel" installed. Right click on a table in a web page to export the table contents to a new excel document. Alternatively from excel you can choose the Data>Import/Export menu and then choose the IE tab/window (by title) to import from.

Comment: Rob, thank you pretty much. This really solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way to proceed.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Run that script and you should have everything you need.

Thanks Joel!

Comment: Thanks ryguy72 for your support, your tip helped me a lot more than the previous one. I could have everthing easealy.

Comment: Click the answer if it helps you.  Let other people know what works.

Comment: ryguy your code inspired me to get where I want, here is the answer:  
Set elems = IE.Document.all
            For Each E In elems
                If (E.getAttribute("id") = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gridDebitosUsuario1_rptContasAberto_ctl01_lblNumeroConta") Then
                    MsgBox E.innertext
                Exit For
            End If
        Next E